# Array and sizeof troubles compiling errors C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation, compiler-errors, sizeof

I'm writing an array-based code that is throwing me some confusing errors after failing to compile. I have searched the internet for sample code that I understand more or less but it is helpful for me to identify errors in my own code / thought process.

The task at hand is to create a function that accepts an array of an unknown amount of integers and sums the even numbers in the array. I am told the last entry of the array is -1, but I don't think this information is useful.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumEven(int myArray[])
{
int len = (sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]));
int i = 0;
int count = 0;

while (i < len)
{
    if (myArray[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
    count = count + myArray[i];
    }
    i++;    
}

return count;
}
```

I attempt to define `len` as the number of array elements. I think this didn't work since one error refers to this line:

```
prog.cpp:13:18: error: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'int *' instead of 'int []' [-Werror,-Wsizeof-array-argument]
int len = (sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]));
                 ^
prog.cpp:11:17: note: declared here
int sumEven(int myArray[])
                ^
1 error generated.
```

I have experience with Matlab, Mathematica, and Python, and so my C++ formatting may be strange. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You don't need to find the length, just iterate until you hit -1.

Comment: I am planning for the case where -1 occurs more than once.

Comment: From the phrasing of your question I took this to be a homework assignment of some sort and that they had told you that the last entry is -1. If that is the condition you are given, than you can stop when you find a -1.  The problem statement basically gives you license to stop at that point so no need to handle the case of an additional -1.

Comment: the name `count` is misleading; it should be `sum` or in that direction

Comment: @pstrjds You are correct, it is an arbitrary practice program for homework, but I would rather plan for more complicated / realistic scenarios in my coding, just for the sake of learning and practice.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf, thanks for the suggestion, it's all in the details.

Comment: FYI, even if this was doing what you wanted `myArray[0]` won't work out well if the function is given a zero element array (i.e., it would trigger undefined behavior).

Comment: The problem is in your scenario (unless they are passing in a std::array) you do not know the length and so even in a real world scenario you would stop when you hit -1 because that is the requirement that you have been given and your code (unfortunately) has to "trust" that you have been given valid input. The specification they have given is a requirement. In a real world scenario you would at least pass in a size parameter, but hopefully since this is C++ you would have a std::vector or other container of that nature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem that can't be properly answered without doing the essential part of the assignment, i.e. giving a fish instead of teaching fishing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when passed as arguments to a function, arrays decays to *pointers* to the first element, so the function

```
int sumEven(int myArray[]) { ... }
```

is actually equal to

```
int sumEven(int *myArray) { ... }
```

And taking the size of a pointer returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

If you need to know the size in the function, you should pass the number of elements as an argument:

```
int sumEven(int *myArray, size_t len) { ... }
```

Comment: Re "the problem is", I see a few more problems.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays *decay to pointers* when you pass them to a function.  That means that the information regarding the size of the array is lost.

This means that `(sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]))` will not do what you want in this context, because here `myArray` is a pointer.

The canonical solution is to add another parameter representing the array size, and use that instead.  This is the approach used in C.

In C++, however, you should probably be using `std:: vector`, unless you have a specific reason to stick with arrays, which are notoriously error-prone.